# MySql access denied after update

Tags: java, mysql

After update of mysql 5.6.26.0, I have a strange situation:

1) I can't access with a simple jdbc connection 
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)

2) the web application (on tomcat) that use the same connection parameters works fine ( probably because the data source use connection created before the update?)

3) It seems I have two instances, yesterday it was one
[image]

4) mysql command line client works fine
[image]

5) Workbench seems to connect to other instance, because I see only test schema
[image]

Comment: simple grant access problem

Comment: so, what I must do? I've only root user